# how do i randomly perform button's action

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm really new to JAVA and I'm making tic tac toe game i finished player vs player and now i want to do player vs cpu what i want to do is when player click on a button for X to appear then cpu will select their button randomly for O to appear but i don't know the code to randomly perform action

I was searching on internet for hour and still no result
here's my code

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   //my code here to set text and background etc
   if(jButton3.getActionCommand().equals("X") && jButton1.getActionCommand().equals("") && jButton2.getActionCommand().equals("")){
                  //this where i wanna random between 2 button action      
    }
```

I want the CPU to choose between

```
jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);

jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
```

but i really have no idea how to do it

Comment: the only random I see in your requirement is showing the button. the action to perform isn't

Comment: I do not understand your question, the human player click must trigger : 1 => update of the tic tac toe model to display the X, 2 => random selection of a free spot in the grid, 3 => update of the model to display the chosen O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My Understanding

I am interpreting your question as **How do I write a function which randomly marks one of the remaining squares with the letter 'O', after the user has performed a move.** Correct me with a comment if I am mistaken.

## Problem Approach

Because I do not know the exact nature of the code representing your cpu player I will provide a high level solution that you can implement.

**1.** Firstly, after a player marks a square with the letter 'X' you must check which squares still remain unmarked. You can do this by initializing an ArrayList of Integers, 1 through 9, at the start of the game which represent the squares (buttons) which are still unmarked.

**Figure: Numbered Tic-Tac-Toe Board**
[image: numbered tic-tac-toe board]

**2.** Second, each time one of the squares is marked, either by the player or the cpu, remove the corresponding Integer from the list.

**3.** Watch for button action events in the way you currently are and add the following code. (our ArrayList of Integers is named unmarked_boxes).

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   //my code here to set text and background etc
   if(jButton3.getActionCommand().equals("X") && jButton1.getActionCommand().equals("") && jButton2.getActionCommand().equals("")){
             Random rand_gen = new Random();
             int index_selected = rand_gen.nextInt(unmarked_boxes.size());
             box_selected = unmarked_boxes.remove(index_selected);
             /*
             here you select and mark the button which corresponds to the box 
             selected. i.e. if the box_selected = 3, then find and mark button3 (not sure 
             how you access your buttons).
             */
    }
```

- In the code I inserted we instantiate and Object of type Random and call its member function nextInt(int bound). This function will generate a number between 0 and the int 'bound'.
- In this case we want to select a square from the entire list of unmarked squares.
- Hence we generated a number between 0 and the number of remaining squares.
- Then we grab (and simultaneously remove) the number which is at 'index_selected' in our list of unmarked_boxes and mark the corresponding button with an 'O'.
- After this point, you need to implement your code to mark the chosen button.

**Note: If you are dead set on selecting between only 2 squares, then forget about the ArrayList approach I have described. Just call rand_gen.nextBoolean() and insert an if statement which picks one button if true and the other if false.**

This should be enough to get you started implementing your solution,

**Good Luck**